# jQuery UI Datepicker today and other days

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui

At the moment, I am using the datepicker jquery ui widget to allow users to pick a date off the calendar.

I want to change what I have so I can have the calendar appear on hover/ click of text saying 'choose your day' and then when the calendar option is clicked, it will redirect to a page.

Is this possible?

Jquery at the moment -

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
  $('#datepicker').datepicker('setDate', 'today');
});
</script>
```

Html

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" size="30" name="date"/>
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.

> and then when the calendar option is clicked, it will redirect to a
>   page.

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ 
     dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', 
     onSelect: function(){
         document.location.href = '/';
     }
});
```

2.

> I can have the calendar appear on hover/ click of text saying 'choose
>   your day'

```
$('#datepicker').on('focus', function(){
   alert('Choose your date');
});
```

Comment: When I say Choose your date, I want that to be in general text. I will have a paragraph saying Please choose your date to....etc etc. And when the user click choose your date, it will pop up with the calendar for selection.